# Determine if view that appears was pushed or came from back button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to tell if a new controller came from a navigation back button or was pushed onto the stack?  Id like to reload data only for pushing on the navigation stack, not on a back button press.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of iOS 5.0 you can do this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.isBeingPresented || self.isMovingToParentViewController) {
        // "self" is being shown for the 1st time, not because of a "back" button.
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work if your view controller is the first view controller on tab of a tab bar controller. It will work the first time, but thereafter switching to it's tab will appear as if it was a back action because neither `isBeingPresented` nor `isMovingToParentViewController` will be true. 

Such a case is rare, but if this is your situation check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/40801594/5152481

Comment: This does not seem to work in iOS10 - both isBeingPresented and isMovingToParentViewController are both false the first time my view controller is presented.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner Are you calling those in `viewWill|DidAppear` or `viewWill|DidDisappear`? They only work in those 4 methods.

Comment: @maddy - Yes, I'm talking about the standard viewWillAppear: method.  Both values on the current VC came up as false in iOS10.

Answer (score 1):

If your push also includes instantiating the view controller, put your push-only logic in `viewDidLoad`. It will not be called on back because it has already been loaded.

Comment: Couldn't viewDidLoad be called on back if the view was unloaded due to memory pressure?

Comment: depends if you unload it or not

Comment: You coudl set a bool ivar called instantiated, then set it to YES at the end of viewDidLoad. Once it is set to yes, don't do the thing you want to only happen once.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the UINavigationControllerDelegate and override the `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:' method. You'll then have to check the returned view controller to make a determination as to whether you came back from the expected view controller.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (yourPushedViewController == viewController)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```