# Can i know in viewWillAppear that it was called after navigationController pop (back button)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewwillappear

Say I have `UIViewController` A and B.
User navigates from A to B with a push segue. 
Than user presses back button and comes to A.

Now `viewWillAppear` of A is called. Can I know in the code here that I came from back button (`navigationController popTo...`) and not by another way? And without writing special code in the B view controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if view that appears was pushed or came from back button in navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849171/determine-if-view-that-appears-was-pushed-or-came-from-back-button-in-navigation)

Answer (score 33):

hm, maybe you can use `self.isMovingToParentViewController` in `viewWillAppear`, see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingToParentViewController), if it is `NO` then it means the current view controller is already on the navigation stack.

Comment: I have tried. It doesn't fit. It looks that there is no solution without writing something in B view controller..

Comment: Yes, this worked for me!! 
        
        if (self.isMovingToParentViewController)
        {
            // Do something the first time only, not on back button
        }

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If the view controller is beneath the one being popped, its `isMovingToParentViewController` is always `false` when called from `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Helps me a lot.

Comment: @Eric That's what the answer is saying.

Answer (score 13):

I like to do the following in view controller A:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (_popping) {
        _popping = false;
        NSLog(@"BECAUSE OF POPPING");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"APPEARING ANOTHER WAY");
    }

    //keep stack size updated
    _stackSize = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;

    ....
}
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    _popping = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > _stackSize;

    ....
}
```

What you are doing is keeping track of whether your view controller (A) is disappearing because a view controller (B) is being pushed or for another reason. Then (if you did not modify the child view controller order) it should accurately tell you if (A) is appearing because of a pop on the navigation controller.

Comment: This will result in unexpected behavior if view controller A gets popped, retained, and push back onto the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Add a BOOL property to `UIViewController` A:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL alreadyAppeared;
```

Then in your `viewWillAppear:` method, add:

```
if (!self.alreadyAppeared) {
    self.alreadyAppeared = YES;
    // Do here the stuff you wanted to do on first appear
}
```

Comment: But A view controller can be appeared by tab bar click also for example (it is alreadyAppeared but not called by back button)

Comment: @adsurbum I used delegate for this case in my app.

Comment: This seems to be the best option for a modal view controller dismissal (I don't want `viewWillAppear` to be called). Adding this bool fixed it.